# why i execute cmd 'kubectl get pods', the pod status is 'NotReady'? it's unreasonable, this status is belong to node status

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, lifecycle, kubernetes-pod

ref:https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/

but the cmd result is(pod:two-containers status is NotReady ):

```
[root@devnet-master ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
busybox-1                        1/1     Running    1          33d
local-volume-provisioner-k49c7   1/1     Running    0          29m
nginx                            2/2     Running    1          21m
two-containers                   1/2     NotReady   0          61m
```

the version is:

```
[root@devnet-master ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T14:18:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T14:12:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

describe pod result is :
[exec describe pod result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX8tO.png)

apply yaml is:
[apply yaml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS8WF.png)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    hostPath:      
      path: /data
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: xxxxxx/nginx:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  - name: debian-container
    image: xxxxxx/debian:stable
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

Comment: This is surprising indeed, never seen this status before, NotReady is usually a status of nodes not pods. What comes up if you do kubectl describe pod two-containers?

Comment: create container is succeed https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX8tO.png

Comment: Can you show the YAML of the `NotReady` pod? We should  find something in the conditions field.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS8WF.png

Comment: Hello @neokeeper. Please provide the requested info by editing your question in a text format instead of posting screenshots. It would be easier to work with.

Comment: i have been update in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pod is being shown in ready status because as per the screenshot you have
  provided it is a multi container pod. Second container naemd "debian-
  container" is in "completed" state because it just had to execute a echo
  command. I suspect you have set the restartPolicy as Onfailure or Never so
  the pod is not restarting. But one of the container inside the pod is in
  running state but the other is not. Hence pod status is in "NotReady"
- "1/2" under "Ready" column in `kubectl get pods` also indicates the
  same that only container is in ready state out of two.